# Creating clones/spawns/unique duplicates in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm an extreme beginner to Corona SDK, and I am currently attempting to make a sound board, where the screen displays multiple buttons, and each button you tap makes a different sound. I am using a process of duplicating an image and having each duplicate play a sound, but I ran into some problems.

Is there a way that I can create "clones" of display objects? What I mean, is that I want to spawn multiple images on the screen, each having some sort of unique value so when one of them is clicked, I will be able to recognize which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
local function onClickButton( event )
    local button = event.target
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        audio.stop() -- Stop ALL current channels
        audio.play( button.stream )
    end
end

local function createButton( params )
    local x = params.x or 0
    local y = params.y or 0
    local audio_location = params.audio or "my_sound.mp3"

    local button = display.newRect( x, y, 50, 50 )
    button.stream = audio.loadStream( audio_location )
    button:addEventListener( "touch", onClickButton )
end

createButton( { x = 100, y = 100, audio = "my_sound.mp3" } )
createButton( { x = 200, y = 100, audio = "my_sound_2.mp3" } )
createButton( { x = 100, y = 200, audio = "my_sound_3.mp3" } )
createButton( { x = 200, y = 200, audio = "my_sound_4.mp3" } )
```

Windows Phone doesn't support MP3's so have that in mind if you're planning on target that market as well:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html

You can also use modular classes with `metatables` but I don't think it's necessary in this case but here is more information about that:
https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!